# Clustering Variables in R and Memory Usage

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I'm trying to calculate clusters of some variables in R with cluster library. The code goes like this:

```
d2 <- dist(ant, method = "euclidian")
```

The problem is that shows this message:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 123.5 Gb
```

It's impossible to have that amount of memory. My dataframe has more than 180000 rows and 12 columns. Any suggestion?

Comment: Apologies in advance if this is a stupid question... Do you really want to cluster 180,000 things with hierarchical clustering? Even after you compute this, it will be very hard to work with, or interpret, or visualize. Would clustering the 12 columns with `dist(t(ant))` be of any use? Otherwise, you can rent an Amazon EC2 linux server with 488GB ram for $5 (USD) per hour, to cluster all rows.

Comment: No problem, I have no experience in clustering. Someone suggest me to cluster the variables. I'm learning. No question is stupid! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Choose an approach that does *not* require a **pairwise distance matrix**, which will always require O(n²) memory... Such algorithms exist several.
2. Simplify your data first. For example, merge duplicates into weights, and use an algorithm/implementation that supports weighted points.
3. Subsample. If you have this many points, you probably do *not* need all of them. Work with a subsample instead.